# typedef redefinition error while trying to compile

Tags: c, typedef

dictionary.h :

```
#ifndef __DICTIONARY_H
#define __DICTIONARY_H

typedef struct Dictionary Dictionary;
.
.
.
#endif
```

dictionary.c :

```
typedef struct Dictionary{

    int* keys;
    int* values;
    int topIndex;
    int keysSize;
    int valuesSize;

}Dictionary;
```

I was told by my instructor to not implement the typedef in the .h file so I did it in my .c file but 
I'm getting errors about redefining it when I try to compile.

I tried to delete the definition in the .h file but got errors because my function who return the typedef now return a non defined type.

How can I solve it?

Comment: "I was told by my instructor to not implement the typedef in the .h" Is this a rule for a specific assignment, or are they saying that as a general rule?

Comment: @ThomasJager yes, it is an assignment and a it's a rule

Comment: `#ifndef __DICTIONARY_H` preprocessor symbols starting with one or two underscores are reserved for the implementation or library. Dont use them.

Comment: @wildplasser I was given the .h file from my instructor, I can't change it

Comment: Find another instructor.

Comment: Please show the exact error messages.

Comment: @wildplasser I wish I could.. alas.. how can I fix it?

Comment: copy/paste the text of the error messages into your question.  Indent them by 4 spaces so they will not be distorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C before C11 doesn't support `typedef` redefinitions.

If you've included a header containing `typedef struct Dictionary Dictionary;`, your `struct Dictionary` definition shouldn't reintroduce the `typedef` name if you want to support those older C implementations. I.e., just do `struct Dictionary{ /*...*/ };` in the C file.